# Nodejs Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, npm

When I run the application, I am getting error getaddrinfo.

I am using mysql for database. So if I run the application,I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere you are trying to connect to a server whose hostname does not resolve to an IP address. Try verifying server hostnames used in your code.